# How to remove failed dpkg .deb installation

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I tried install .deb file using the `dpkg -i` command. However the installation failed, when I tried `sudo apt-get install -f` I just get this error:

```
--
Installing init scripts.
Sweet! Please run `prey config gui` to finish installation.
Voila! All good.
dpkg: error processing package prey (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
prey

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Now when I try and run any apt-get command it finishes with this error is there any any way to stop apt-get from trying to finish the installation?

Output of  `cat /var/lib/dpkg/status |grep prey`
is

```
Package: prey
Source: prey
Provides: prey
Homepage: http://preyproject.com
```

Comment: have you tried sudo apt-get purge prey  ?

Comment: It worked I had tried autoremove, add it and I will mark it as the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will purge the broken package and conf

```
 sudo apt-get purge prey
```